# AltRecipient AD attribute on mail enabled Public Folder cannot be synchronized in hybrid environment with O365

Tags: entra-id, public-folders, exchange-hybrid

We have a hyrbid environment setup between Exchange 2010 and O365 for both mailboxes and Public Folders. Since putting Public Folders in hyrbid mode (through use of https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/collaboration-exo/public-folders/set-up-legacy-hybrid-public-folders ) we keep getting reports every export cycle containing the below for each mail enabled Public Folders:

```
The reference attribute [AltRecipient] could not be updated in Azure Active Directory. Remove the reference [PublicFolder] in your local Active Directory directory service.
```

Does anyone know why Azure has an issue with the AD attribute that stores forwarding address', which I understand once the Public Folders are migrated can have this functionality enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Which step did you get the error message?

Based on my knowledge, if you want to sync the attribute [AltRecipient] in Azure Active Directory, it requires Azure AD Connect build 1.1.552.0 or after. Please make sure that AAD connect is up to date.

Comment: Not sure what you mean which step. The error reports get e-mailed to us. Looks like we have a version above the minimum - https://imgur.com/a/FdP6dgo

Answer (score 0):

After check in the following article, it seems that this attribute cannot be synced:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19901.dirsync-list-of-attributes-that-are-synced-by-the-azure-active-directory-sync-tool.aspx

This is by design. The forwarding configuration is not being migrated, or synchronized to Office 365. The 2 attributes, DeliverToMailboxAndForward and ForwardingAddress, correspond to the following 2 attributes in local AD: altRecipient and deliverAndRedirect, which are not being synchronized to Office 365 by the DirSync tool.

I suggest attempt to change that value using PowerShell:

Set-MailPublicFolder -Identity \CCC\Info -ForwardingAddress "{EmailPII}@contoso.com"

Comment: Your previous [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/955024/#955219) on this question dealt with Azure AD Connect, and like the article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-sync-attributes-synchronized mentions, needs to have the sync tool be version 1.1.552.0 or higher (which I confirmed we have). This answer links to a legacy sync tool called DirSync, which we don't use, and actually links to the Azure AD Connect page on synced attributes. We seem to be going backwards.

Comment: You can check this in AAD connect, and make sure this forwarding attribute is synces.